# set_value() Does Not Maintain the Field's Value

Tags: php, codeigniter

**Set value does not maintain the field value when i get validation errors.**

*View*:**

```
echo form_input('post_title', set_value('post_title'));
```

**Controller:**

```
if ($this->form_validation->run('post_ad') == FALSE)
{
    set_temporary_msg(validation_errors('<div>', '</div>'));  
}
```

**Helper:**

```
function set_temporary_msg($msg, $target_location = '') 
{
    $CI =& get_instance();
    $CI->session->set_flashdata('temp_msg', $msg);
    redirect($target_location); 
}

function get_temporary_msg() {

    $CI =& get_instance();
    echo $CI->session->flashdata('temp_msg');

}
```

If some input are invalid, set_temporary_msg() is called.
At the top of the ***View*** page, i echo get_temporary_msg();

**Error messages and redirection work fine, but i lose all set_value(). Any idea how to solve this issue?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's normal, if you make a redirection after form submited, set_value can't find value of post_title because $_POST become empty. If you want to keep value submited you have to pass it in your redirect url or in session.
Sorry for my poor english..